# I cant use the tk.Tk(), and I dont know why :(

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was trying to create a program but first I wanted to try creating a window, but it won't let me use the command even when I put only the first two lines. I use Spyder 5.0.3. I realized that when I create a new .py file regardless of the name it does not let me create a window, but with another program that I had if it worked :(

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana=tk.Tk()
ventana.title("asfas")
ventana.geometry('400x400')
ventana.config(background='light grey')
etiqueta1=tk.Label(ventana,text="Escribe tu frase",bg="seashell",fg="black")
etiqueta1.pack(fill=tk.X)

etiqueta1=tk.Label(ventana,text="Sap",bg="seashell",fg="black")
etiqueta1.pack(padx=20,pady=20)
```

This is what appears in the console

> "runfile('C:/Users/leoja/Desktop/ventanasfa.py',
> wdir='C:/Users/leoja/Desktop') Reloaded modules:
> jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop,
> tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen,
> zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil,
> jupyter_client.adapter, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version,
> PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util,
> PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model"

Please help, sometimes this happens to me and I want to know why it is: /

Comment: Don't know much about `Spyder` but aren't you missing `ventana.mainloop()` at the end? Is that doesn't work, I would reinstall `Spyder` or `python` or both

Comment: ohhhhh right... I totally forgot about that hahaha thank you but still, what does "Reloaded modules" mean?